# How to make two phone apps communicate

Tags: android, iphone, location, status

I am new to the phone development and this question came up:

Lets say I have two(or more) people standing in a room, each with the same model of phone.  How, if they are running my app, would the apps/phones communicate and update each other.  An example would be if each phone was transmitting location information to the other users of the app.  Does android have build in client/server functionality?

I am sorry if this is a little broad but as I said I am new to this and am just trying to get an idea of what is going on.

The app itself is a 'party' app, with people in a room with the ability to update their status which is then broadcast to the rest of the people in the room.

Thanks for the replies.  I think we are going to change the model but it was good to have some ideas as to where to look/what to research.  Thanks.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't get your question, are you asking about a certain app how they have it done, or are you asking how to do communications between different devices in general? Also do you mean with or without the presence of Internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at GameKit.  There are peer-to-peer protocols and client/server protocols.  They're pretty easy to implement, and there's sample code about.  Check out the info at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html

Comment: Note that you don't have to use GameCenter to use GameKit.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for some ideas to kickstart the research.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: The link is dead. Plus its been a few years now. Any update on the topic? Interested in knowing if this is available in android now.

Answer (score 0):

**Bluetooth** would work considering that the phones are in the same room, even with different models or even between iOS and Android.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for some ideas to kickstart the research.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the concept of Publish/Subscribe hubs. Granted, it's not direct communication between the two devices as there is a message broker inbetween.

Only two of them come to mind right now: Redis.io and Pubsub.io (there is one called pubsubhububub or something similar too)

Choosing the medium for communication is a completely different question though, that's really highly dependent on your application and it's context. BT, WiFi, GSM, NFC, etc. are all good! They have their respective pros and cons, and you should choose the best one for your app.